# How to write Enhanced for loops in Java

Tags: java, foreach

I am trying to write this `for loop` using `enhanced for loop` but it gives me error **The method get(int) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (Employee)**

I know it's because method ArrayLists's `get()` requires an `Integer` type data type as the argument, but I need to convert this to enhanced for loop. This is what I tried so far.

This is the original code with `traditional for loop`

```
//display employees
    public void outputEmployee(ArrayList<Employee> list) {

        System.out.println("Employee ID" + "\t\t" + "Full Name" + "\t\t" + "Address" + "\t\t" + "Faculty Name" + "\t\t"
                + "Department" + "\t\t" + "Designation" + "\n");
        System.out.println(
                "================================================================================================================");

        for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            Employee employee = list.get(i);
            System.out.println(employee.getEmployeeId() + "\t" + employee.getEmployeeFullName() + "\t\t" + employee.getEmployeeAddress() + "\t"
                    + employee.getFacultyName() + "\t" + employee.getDepartment() + "\t" + employee.getEmployeeDesignation() + "\n");
            System.out.println(
                    "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        }           

    }
```

and here is what I tried:

```
//display employees
    public void outputEmployee(ArrayList<Employee> list) {

        System.out.println("Employee ID" + "\t\t" + "Full Name" + "\t\t" + "Address" + "\t\t" + "Faculty Name" + "\t\t"
                + "Department" + "\t\t" + "Designation" + "\n");
        System.out.println(
                "================================================================================================================");        

        for(Employee emp : list) {
            Employee employee = list.get(emp); //gives error here
            System.out.println(employee.getEmployeeId() + "\t" + employee.getEmployeeFullName() + "\t\t" + employee.getEmployeeAddress() + "\t"
                    + employee.getFacultyName() + "\t" + employee.getDepartment() + "\t" + employee.getEmployeeDesignation() + "\n");
            System.out.println(
                    "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        }

    }
```

can someone help me please?

Comment: This statement `Employee employee = list.get(i);` in for loop is equal to `emp` in enhanced for loop

Comment: you are trying to use `list.get(emp);` when you are using enhanced for each doesn't need to do that.
you just need to write `Employee employee = emp;`

Comment: Thank you @Deadpool and Dushyant:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are traversing with for-each loop you can directly use `emp` instance. or if you want to assign it to new instance then you can use `Employee employee = emp;`

Comment: Why having that second instance at all?

Comment: @Escort Personal Adz I really hope you did not just fix your issue by making a new instance, that is completely defeating the point of using an enhanced `for` loop and serves no purpose.  Just use the `emp` directly.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
for(Employee emp : list) {
  Employee employee = list.get(emp); //gives error here
```

That second line isn't required at all. You are **already** iterating the members of your list. The `emp` variable/reference points to the members of that list.

So you just go

```
System.out.println(emp.getEmployeeId() ...
```

Or, alternatively, change your loop to

```
for(Employee employee : list) { ...
```

That is all there is to this.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(Employee emp : list) {
            Employee employee = list.get(emp); //gives error here
```

That gives a problem .. well, so it should. 
There is only one `get` method in the ArrayList class, and it takes an int as parameter (the index).

emp in your code is not an index, it already is the instance of Employee.
So, replace those lines by:

```
for ( Employee employee : list) {
```

Comment: This is a wrong answer

Comment: What is wrong about it? There is no need for a second variable. I can assure you, this will solve your issue. If not show how you tried it, and we may fix the (new) issue

Comment: list.get() -> this accept only `int` data type. but you have put an `Employee` type.

Comment: He is saying remove the `get`, he is not wrong.

Comment: @EscortPersonalAdz yes, I know. But seeing as you already have the instance of Employee, you don't need to run the get to get an instance of Employee. All you need to do, is to change emp to employee in your for statement, and remove the get call.

Answer (score 0):

Enhanced loop already gives you the object, you can use it like this:

```
for(Employee emp : list) {
    System.out.println(emp.getEmployeeId());
}

Employee employee = list.get(emp);
```

This gives error because Java expects the argument 
to be an int, for example list.get(2);

Comment: Your code won't even compile. You can't use emp as variable name and then use employee later on

Comment: Yeah, i made a typo